# Difference in mongo --version and mongosh --version

Tags: database, mongodb, homebrew

In the Terminal, when i type in **mongosh --version** i get **1.0.7**, but when i type **mongo --version** i get

```
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "6d9ec525e78465dcecadcff99cce953d380fedc8",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Is there any problem in this, since mongosh and mongo are different versions? Can i normally use mongoDB?

Comment: They are just different tools and hence different versions. `mongosh` is a recent introduction and `mongo` shell has been there for a while. Both these are command-line tools to access MongoDB server. Both have similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you. @prasad_

Answer (score 7):

As @prasad pointed out, mongosh is the newer tool.

See company blog post here: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-the-new-shell

Quote from the blog post above here:

> Since the beginning, MongoDB has had a shell (mongo) and almost
> everybody who’s ever used MongoDB has used it for one reason or
> another. From running simple queries to scripting admin operations,
> our users use the shell almost every day, several times a day.
>
> The more MongoDB grows as a data platform and it expands with new
> functionality and new products, the more the shell needs to do. We
> have considered how to extend mongo to grow along with the MongoDB
> platform, but we’ve come to realize that this would not have been the
> right approach.
>
> For this reason, we went back to the drawing board and designed a new
> MongoDB Shell from the ground up. The new MongoDB Shell is built to be
> extensible, so we can easily add new functionality as new products and
> services are added to the MongoDB platform, it’s embeddable, so in
> addition to using it in your terminal, you can use it (or parts of it)
> inside other products (one example of this is MongoDB for VS Code),
> and last but not least it provides a modern command-line experience
> with enhanced usability features.
>
> The MongoDB Shell is a standalone product, it’s developed separately
> from the MongoDB Server and it’s open-source under the Apache 2
> license.

Comment: Worth noting that the legacy mongo shell was deprecated in mongo v5 (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongo/) and I think removed in v6 (at least in the docker image)

Comment: I wish this elaborated on, when to use one or the other. I seems that `mongo` is being phased out. But I'm not sure if it's completely - or just for the interactive shell part.